# How to customize telnet login prompt on linux

Tags: linux, configuration, authentication, pam, telnet

When I run `login` command on debian, I get:

```
hostname login: _
```

on RHEL5, Solaris or HP-UX I get:

```
login: _
```

I need to be able to customize `login:` and `password:` prompts it on a Linux box. I can recompile the package, but is there a better (easier) way to do it?

I was looking for some PAM config option but didn't find anything.

I know it can be done with the [pam_set_item()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pam_set_item) function using `PAM_USER_PROMPT` constant, but is there a way to do such customization in a `/etc/pam.d/*` config file?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I need this to customize telnet username and password prompt. However, `telnetd` is using `/bin/login` for that prompt, this is why I asked for `login` customization in this question.

Comment: I wasn't sure where to ask this question. I was considering also ServerFault, but I expected more PAM experts here.

Comment: Are you wanting to change for console or ssh connection?

Comment: @BernieWhite: SSH is not an option (unfortunately). I need that for telnet server which (as far as I know) is using `login` binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try to change system locale to your custom locale containing desired labels.

Comment: Yes, I just noted that "login:" and "password:" from `login` is locale aware. This might be best alternative for a recompiling the package.

Comment: It tuns out that "login: " is taken from `/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/shadow.mo`, while "Password: " is taken from another `/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/Linux-PAM.mo` file.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `mingetty` then you can specify the `--nohostname` parameter in `/etc/inittab`

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty --nohostname tty1
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty --nohostname tty2



--nohostname
          Do not print the hostname before the login prompt.
```

Comment: I cannot use `mingetty`. See comment for Mike's answer.

Answer (score 1):

if you use mgetty in /etc/inittab you can append the -p flag to change the login prompt

```
man mgetty


   -p <login prompt>
          Use the given string to prompt users for their login names. Various tokens are allowed in this string. These tokens are: @ for the system name, \n, \g, \f,  for  new-
          line, bell, and form feed, respectively.  \v and \r will expand to the OS version and release.  \P, \l and \L will expand to the tty name ("ttyS0").  \Y will give the
          Caller ID, \I the "CONNECT foobar" string returned by the modem, and \S or \b will output the port speed.  \N and \U give the number of users currently logged in.  \C
          will  be  changed  into  the result of ctime(), and \D or \d and \t or \T will output the date and time, respectively. Finally, \<digit> will use digit as octal/deci-
          mal/hexadecimal representation of the character to follow.

          The default prompt is specified at compile time.
```

Comment: Sorry, I cannot use `mgetty`. It's needed for telnetd login prompt customization, and telnet calls `/bin/login`. It must work with `/bin/login` alone.

Answer (score 1):

It have found that `telnetd` accepts `-L /path/to/login` option, so I have written few lines of python code to provide my own `/bin/login` alternative using PAM to authenticate and `login -f` to open a login shell.

In that python script I can define whatever prompt I need for both `login:` and `password:`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `telnetd` man page, with default options it asks for credentials, not `login`.

It also has this option:

```
   -h     Disables  the printing of host-specific information before login
          has been completed.
```

Presumably you're invoking `telnetd` with that option - if you remove it does it give you the desired behaviour?

Comment: Thanks MikeyB. I need to change the prompt to something completely different. In other words, I need to be able to change prompt for example to: "Hello, what's your user name ?" and "your password please...".

Comment: The -h option MikeyB mentions is used to control the display of /etc/issue.net before the line with the login: prompt, and has no effect on the display of the hostname on that line.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, to change the `Password:` prompt, you can define a `LOGIN_STRING` in `/etc/login.defs`, something like this:

```
LOGIN_STRING        "%s, Please enter your password: "
```

*(`%s` will be replaced by user name)*

but in fact, this option seems obsolete and doesn't work anymore:

```
configuration error - unknown item 'LOGIN_STRING' (notify administrator)
```

It is also mentioned in `/etc/login.defs`:

```
# XXX - it doesn't work correctly yet, for now leave it commented out
# to use the default which is just "Password: ".
```

About the `login:` prompt, you can change it either by setting the `PAM_USER_PROMPT` or recompiling the `login-utils` package:

```
/*
 * Andrew.Taylor@cal.montage.ca: Provide a user prompt to PAM
 * so that the "login: " prompt gets localized. Unfortunately,
 * PAM doesn't have an interface to specify the "Password: " string
 * (yet).
 */
retcode = pam_set_item(pamh, PAM_USER_PROMPT, _("login: "));
PAM_FAIL_CHECK;
```